# A variant of Jensen inequality when the function is not everywhere convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, average, functional-inequalities

Let  $F:(0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^1$ function satisfying $F(1)=0$, which is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$, and strictly decreasing on $(0,1]$.

Suppose also that $F$ is convex on $(0,1]$.

Finally, let $g:X \to (0,\infty)$ be a measurable function defined on a probability space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$, with  $\int_X g \in (0,1)$.

> Does $F(\int_X g) \le\int_X F\circ g\,\,$ ?

If $\text{Image}(g)$ was contained in $(0,1]$, this would follow from a standard application of Jensen inequality. Here I am allowing $g$ to obtain values which lie outside the domain where $F$ is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The point $\left(\int_X g, \int_X F\circ g\right)\in\mathbb R^2$ is contained in the convex hull of the set $G=\{(x,F(x)): x\ge0\}$, which in turn is contained in the epigraph $S$ of the convex function $F^*$ given by $F^*(x)=F(\min(x,1))$.
Note that $F^*\le F$ pointwise, and $F(x)=F^*(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$.
Since  $\int_X g\in(0,1)$, we have $F\left(\int_X g\right)=F^*\left(\int_X g\right).$
Since $F^*$ is convex, we have $F^*(\int_X g)\le \int_X F^*{\circ} g$ and then $F\left(\int_X g\right)\le\int_X F{\circ} g,$   as desired.

Added, in reaction to a comment:

Expressed in a different language, your problem is this:  Suppose $F$ is as you specify, and the non-negative random variable $X$ satisfies $E[X]\in(0,1)$; you want to know if the expectation of the random vector $(X,Y)=(X,F(X))$ lies above the graph of $F$.  In general vector expectations are elements of the closed convex hull of their vectorial support. In your case the vectorial support is the set I call $G$ above.
Your probability measure $\mu$ induces a distribution of mass on $G$;
the centroid of this distribution is the vectorial expectation $(E[X],E[Y])$.  The convex hull of $G$ is of course convex, without any assumption on $F$.  In your special case, $F$ restricted to $[0,1]$ is convex, and $F^*$ defined by $F^*(x)=F(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $F^*(x)=0$ for $x>1$ is also convex.  So Jensen applies to $F^*$ and so on.

I thought of this method in the current problem because I think of all Jensen inequality arguments this way, in "moment space".  There is an underlying probability measure, with a centroid, and what is desired is to know if the centroid is contained in a certain convex set. In your case, the epigraph of $F$ need not be a convex set, but its intersection with the half plane cut out by $x\le 1$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very interesting answer. I am not sure that I follow the intention of your comments at the beginning though; "The point $\left(\int_X g, \int_X F\circ g\right)$ is contained in the convex hull of the set $G=\{(x,F(x)): x\ge0\}$..." -we only know that *after* we prove that $F\left(\int_X g\right)\le\int_X F{\circ} g$, right? (So I am not sure whether these are more of "concluding remarks", or something which provides visual intuition for what's going on...Can you say anything on how did you come up with this proof?).

Comment: No, it is not a concluding remark, but a starting point.  I will try to edit my post to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really clear and illuminating explanation. I really like your view of  Jensen inequality through convex hulls and "vectorial" expectations. I wonder, is this insight taken from some specific source? BTW, I am not sure how to formally prove the assertion about the convex hulls (although it seems very intuitive)-I asked about this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671240/how-to-prove-that-the-expectation-of-a-random-vector-lies-in-the-convex-hull-of . Finally, is the term vectorial support a standard one?

Comment: Robert Israel's hint/answer to your question is exactly right. I think I was exposed to this point of view early on and often thereafter: in my first uni maths course we had Minkowski's convex body theorem, Lyapunoff's theorem, Caratheodory's theorem, then in graduate school I read Phelp's book on Choquet theory, and then I had an enthusiastic colleague who was an expert user of these techniques.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds very interesting. One last question-we do really need here the fact that $F$ is convex up to $(0,1)$? That is, if we only assume that $F$ is convex on $(0,\int_X g)$, does that guarantee $F\left(\int_X g\right)\le\int_X F{\circ} g$?

Comment: I think that I convinced myself that convexity up to $\int_X g$ does not suffice...

Comment: Composed before reading your previous. What's important in this argument is that what I call $F^*$ must be convex over $\mathbb R^+$ (because we use Jensen on it), that $F^*(x)\le F(x)$ for all $x>0$ (so as not to spoil the fruits of Jensen), and $F^*=F$ at the single point at $\int_X g$ (to extract the desired result).  Why don't you formulate a separate question on the broader question of weakening the convexity restriction on Jensen?